# Webpack: prevent a function with a specific name from getting uglified in production?

Tags: webpack

I need a specific function (internal function in a third-party package, so importing it and using Object.defineProperty() to set its name is not ideal) to keep its name in the production bundle. Is there any way to configure Webpack for this?

Comment: What plugin(s) are you using for uglification?

Comment: Just babel-loader and ts-loader, no other explicit plugins, just the standard configuration.

Answer (score 1):

Using [webpack-terser-plugin](https://webpack.js.org/plugins/terser-webpack-plugin), you can configure [`terserOptions`](https://webpack.js.org/plugins/terser-webpack-plugin/#terseroptions) to exclude certain words by specifying an array of strings under `mangle.reserved`. For example, if you want to ensure that `myUtilityFunction` doesn't get mangled, you would use this configuration in your `webpack.config.js`:

```js
const TerserPlugin = require('webpack-terser-plugin');

module.exports = {
  optimization: {
    minimize: true,
    minimizer: [
      new TerserPlugin({
        terserOptions: {
          mangle: {
            reserved: ['myUtilityFunction'], // <-- list reserved words here
          },
        },
      }),
    ],
  },
};
```

For a full list of minification options, see [here](https://github.com/terser/terser#minify-options).